# create new array from existing array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multiple arrays like this:

```
array (
[floorBuildingName] => Array
    (
        [0] => Lt.1
        [1] => Lt.2
    )

[roomFloorName] => Array
    (
        [0] => Single
        [1] => Medium1
        [2] => MaXI
    )
)
```

I would like to merge the two arrays into a single array.

For example:

```
array (
 [0] => array(
     [0] =>Lt.1,
     [1] =>Single
   ),
 [1] => array(
     [0] =>Lt.2,
     [1] =>Medium1
   ),
  [2] => array(
     [0] =>Lt.2,
     [1] =>MaXI
   )
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is not clear how you want to merge the two arrays. For example, why does Lt.1 go with single and Lt.2 go with Medium1 and MaXI. Are these always going to be the only values of the 2 arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `array_map` very Easily:

Try this code:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2);
$arr2 = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

while(count($arr1) != count($arr2)) {
    //If Array1 is Shorter then Array2
    if (count($arr1)<count($arr2)) {
        $arr1[] = $arr1[count($arr1) - 1];
    }
    //If Array2 is Shorter then Array1
    if (count($arr1) > count($arr2)) {
        $arr2[] = $arr2[count($arr2) - 1];
    }
}
//Now merge arrays
$newarray = (array_map(null, $arr1, $arr2));


print_r($newarray);
```

Will Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => three
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => four
        )
)
```

Comment: The problem is, you need to have arrays with the same number of arguments.

Comment: Also, the OP hasn't really explained how it wants to the two merged. It looks like it is a simple merge, but maybe we need some more information from the problem domain to see what the merged array means, it might have to be more calculated than a simple merge.

Answer (score 0):

there's the solution for different number of arguments:

```
$floorBuildingName = array(
        'Lt.1',
        'Lt.2'
    );
$roomFloorName = array(
        'Single', 'Medium1', 'MaXI'
);

class ValueArrayIterator extends ArrayIterator
{

    protected $arrays;

    protected $latestValues = [];

    public function __construct(array $mainArray) {
        parent::__construct($mainArray);
        $this->arrays = func_get_args();
    }

    public function current()
    {
        $returnValue = [];

        foreach ($this->arrays as $arrayKey => $array) {
            if (isset($array[$this->key()])) {
                $this->latestValues[$arrayKey] = $array[$this->key()];
            }
            $returnValue[] = $this->latestValues[$arrayKey];
        }

        return $returnValue;
    }
}

$iterator = new ValueArrayIterator($roomFloorName, $floorBuildingName);
$newArray = iterator_to_array($iterator);
```

Comment: Hi, unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so], as other users can already look at the user profile to view information about you. For more information, see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to determine the maximum array length. Then, create a new array and finally, put the elements at the given index into the new array. If the index is out of bounds, then use the last element.

```
var $maxNumber = 0;
foreach ($myArray as $array) {
    $maxNumber = max($maxNumber, count($array));
}

$result = array();
for ($index = 0; $index < $maxNumber; $index++) {
    $result[] = array();
    foreach($myArray as $array) {
        if (count($array) < $maxNumber) {
            $result[$index][] = $array(count($array) - 1);
        } else {
            $result[$index][] = $array[$index];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to pad out uneven arrays with the last value in the array:

```
$data = ['floorBuildingName' => [..], ..];

// find the longest inner array
$max = max(array_map('count', $data));

// pad all arrays to the longest length
$data = array_map(function ($array) use ($max) {
    return array_pad($array, $max, end($array));
}, $data);

// merge them
$merged = array_map(null, $data['floorBuildingName'], $data['roomFloorName']);
```